# Display both values of same column after comparing rows (with inner join)

Tags: sql, postgresql

When you perform an inner join to compare 2 values of the same column, but different rows, with eachother. How do you include both compared values of the same column? Without error "column specified more than once"

In the new table I want to see a.var2 and b.var2.

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS
SELECT
    a.var1,
    a.var2,
    CASE WHEN a.var2 = b.var2 THEN 'yes' AS equal
FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE var3 = x
    ) a
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE var3 = y
    ) b ON a.var1 = b.var1
```

Comment: When creating a table you have to use distinct names for all the columns. You can alias columns to rename them if necessary. But you don't have duplicate names in the statement you posted. The statement is syntactically invalid though, there's no `END` for the `CASE`.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve here. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: CASE WHEN a.var2 = b.var2 THEN 'yes'  ELSE 'no' END AS equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need alias names for the two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS
SELECT
  a.var1,
  a.var2 AS a_var2,
  b.var2 AS b_var2,
  a.var2 = b.var2 AS equal
FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE var3 = 'x') a
JOIN (SELECT * FROM table WHERE var3 = 'y') b ON a.var1 = b.var1;
```

PostgreSQL has a boolean type. I am using this in above query and I generally recommend doing so, instead of using a string with 'yes'/'no', 'YES'/'NO', 'Y'/'N' or whatever values you happen to decide for. The boolean data type is the appropriate type here. In this specific case, though, I wouldn't write it at all, because the information is redundant. Just look at the two columns and you see whether they are equal or not.